# Error while opening site in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm getting an error while trying to open the site in sharepoint designer 2013. This was working till yesterday. Don't know the reason for this. I have got the below error message, when I have tried to open it from UI using Page->Edit in Designer link.
[image]

Any idea on this ?

PS: My Sharepoint server is also 2013.

EDIT:

See the error message while try to open manually

[image]
[image]

Comment: Where is error message?
can you try to open your site url through Designer manually, instead of `UI using Page->Edit in Designer link`

Comment: Please see the error messages above.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1.Start SharePoint 2013 Central Administration, and then click Security.

2.Click Specify authentication providers.

3.If the Web application in the Web Application list is not the same application that you want to open in SharePoint Designer 2013, click Web Application on the Change Web Application list.

4.On the Select Web Application page, click the name of the Web application that you want to open.

5.Under Zone, Click Default to open the Edit Authentication page.

6.Under Enable Client Integration, click Yes, and then click Save.

[Reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981223?wa=wsignin1.0)

If that does not help try enabling anonymous authentication for the SharePoint web application in IIS.  [reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2758431)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried the same already. But, still the same error!

Comment: Try the following link. I feel its a permission issue.http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/07/11/test-permissions-grid.aspx